# how to show all alphabates in glossary block in drupal 7?

Tags: views

I have a glossary view in drupal 7 with attachment. These attachment missing some alphabates. showing like a|c|d|h|m etc. But I need a|b|c|d|e|f etc like this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this module?

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_glossary

It provides exact same functionality.

Comment: Its also giving me same result